# In GHC- Why is the lazy version of this small program so much faster than the loop based variant?

Tags: haskell

These two programs do the same thing, but one runs 10x faster.

This takes approx. 10 seconds on my machine:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

theValueOne=B.singleton 1

main = replicateM_ 100000000 $ B.putStr theValueOne
```

The second version uses output-lazy IO.  It is done in about 1 second (as fast as c):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main = BL.putStr $ BL.pack $ replicate 100000000 1
```

Question: Why is the non-lazy version so slow?  More importantly, how can I make it fast?  (I've tried recursion, `forM`, modifying the output buffer using `hSetBuffering`...  Nothing has made a difference)

---

Note- This is more than just an academic question.  The non-lazy version is an extremely simplified version of an executable my company uses in production, which is also slow in the same way.  It would be nearly impossible to re-architect the larger program around the analogous lazy solution.

Comment: The lazy one has to build up a giant list in memory before you actually call `putStr`. The strict one is calling `putStr` on each value immediately, and discarding the result of the action. No list is built, and constant space is used.

Comment: @chepner I didn't show my c version, but it also calls `fwrite` per byte, so I doubt that an excess of `putStr` calls would make a difference.

Comment: @chepner How does that explain why the lazy one is faster?

Comment: Oh, good question. I had the two mixed up.

Comment: I feel like the lazy one writes more than one byte at a time, no?

Comment: How are you compiling/running/timing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated:*  Added possible source of problem and a solution.

I don't think it has anything to do with lazy I/O.  If you rewrite the strict I/O version to write two bytes at once:

```
theValueOne = B.singleton 1
main = replicateM_ 50000000 $ B.putStr (theValueOne <> theValueOne)
```

that halves the time.  Write ten bytes at once:

```
theValueOne = B.singleton 1
main = replicateM_ 10000000 $ B.putStr (foldMap id (replicate 10 theValueOne))
```

and it's already faster than the lazy I/O version.

The issue is that there's a bit of overhead in a `B.hPutStr` call, much more than the overhead of a C `fwrite` call, and it's just not a particularly efficient way to write a single byte.

A good chunk of the overhead comes from the fact that Haskell I/O buffers have immutable metadata.  Even though the buffer *content* itself is mutable, the pointers to valid data within the buffer [are immutable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-IO-Buffer.html), and so writing a single byte requires a heap allocation of a new `GHC.IO.Buffer.Buffer` structure which GHC can't optimize away

One solution is to use a hand-crafted buffering structure with a mutable pointer.  The following works, and it's about twice as fast as the lazy I/O version in the original question.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import Data.Word
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable
import System.IO

data WriteBuffer = WriteBuffer
  { handle :: !Handle
  , capacity :: !Int
  , used :: !(IORef Int)
  , content :: !(ForeignPtr Word8)
  }

newBuffer :: Handle -> IO WriteBuffer
newBuffer h = do
  hSetBinaryMode h True
  hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
  WriteBuffer h cap <$> newIORef 0 <*> mallocForeignPtrBytes cap
  where cap = 4096

flushBuffer :: WriteBuffer -> IO ()
flushBuffer WriteBuffer{..} = do
  n <- readIORef used
  withForeignPtr content $ \p -> hPutBuf handle p n
  writeIORef used 0

writeByte :: Word8 -> WriteBuffer -> IO ()
writeByte w buf@(WriteBuffer{..}) = do
  n <- readIORef used
  withForeignPtr content $ \p -> poke (plusPtr p n) w
  let n' = n + 1
  writeIORef used n'
  when (n' == capacity) $
    flushBuffer buf

main :: IO ()
main = do
  b <- newBuffer stdout
  replicateM_ 100000000 (writeByte 1 b)
  flushBuffer b
```

Someone ironically, converting this to a version using an immutable counter  and passing the `WriteBuffer` as state through `foldM` doubles the speed again, so it's about 4 times as fast as the lazy I/O version in the original question:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Word
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Storable
import System.IO

data WriteBuffer = WriteBuffer
  { handle :: !Handle
  , capacity :: !Int
  , used :: !Int
  , content :: !(ForeignPtr Word8)
  }

newBuffer :: Handle -> IO WriteBuffer
newBuffer h = do
  hSetBinaryMode h True
  hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
  WriteBuffer h cap 0 <$> mallocForeignPtrBytes cap
  where cap = 4096

flushBuffer :: WriteBuffer -> IO WriteBuffer
flushBuffer buf@WriteBuffer{..} = do
  withForeignPtr content $ \p -> hPutBuf handle p used
  return $ buf { used = 0 }

writeByte :: Word8 -> WriteBuffer -> IO WriteBuffer
writeByte w buf@(WriteBuffer{..}) = do
  withForeignPtr content $ \p -> poke (plusPtr p used) w
  let used' = used + 1
      buf' = buf { used = used' }
  if (used' == capacity)
    then flushBuffer buf'
    else return buf'

main :: IO ()
main = do
  b <- newBuffer stdout
  b' <- foldM (\s _ -> writeByte 1 s) b [(1::Int)..100000000]
  void (flushBuffer b')
```

The reason this one is so fast seems to be that GHC is able to optimize away the `WriteBuffer` constructor entirely from the fold and just pass around unboxed pointers and integers in the loop.  My guess is that if I modified the mutable version above to avoid boxing and unboxing the integer in the `used` IORef, it would be similarly fast.

Comment: You are correct....  I put in nanosecond level timing around `B.putStr` and `fwrite`, and can clearly see that the former is about 10x slower....  Now the question is why, and how do I get around this.  Either way, I'll consider this question solved.